# Palindrome, arraylist,

Tags: java

Check if the word is a palindrome or not. If palindrome, store the letters in an arraylist.
Remove all the vowels in the arraylist and store in another arraylist. Output all the vowels. If not palindrome, return 
the program.

```
import java.util.*;
    class Palindrome
    {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
        ArrayList< String > words = new ArrayList< String >();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    
        while(scan.hasNext())     
           words.add(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Is it a palindrome? " +
              isPalindrome(words));
      }
      static boolean isPalindrome(ArrayList< String > w)
      {
       int front  = 0, back = w.size() - 1;
       while( front < back)
         if (!w.get(front++).equals(w.get(back--)))
            return false;
        return true;
      }
    }
```

I have a code for Palindrome but I am not quite sure what the question wants and I have no idea on how to answer the question. Can anybody give me an answer or a hint that I can easily understand? Honestly, I don't know how to start this. I'm quite new to this.

---

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PalindromeWierd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Character> palim = new ArrayList<Character>();
        palim.add('b');
        palim.add('c');
        palim.add('d');
        palim.add('f');
        palim.add('g');
    palim.add('h');
    palim.add('j');
    palim.add('k');
    palim.add('l');
    palim.add('m');
    palim.add('n');
    palim.add('p');
    palim.add('q');
    palim.add('r');
    palim.add('s');
    palim.add('t');
    palim.add('v');
    palim.add('w');
    palim.add('x');
    palim.add('y');
    palim.add('z');
        System.out.println("Palim with vowels: ");
        for (Character character : palim) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Character> palimWithoutVowels = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (Character character : palim) {
            if (character != 'a' && character != 'e' && character != 'i'
                    && character != 'o' && character != 'u') {
                palimWithoutVowels.add(character);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Palim without vowels: ");
        for (Character character : palimWithoutVowels) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: All I understand is that I have to input a palindre code, which consists the palindre to determine the word that the user will give if it is a palindre or not. I don't know how to remove all the vowels in the arraylist and store in another arraylist.

Comment: to remove vowels you will have to iterate on the string and check if each character is a,e,i,o, or u.

Comment: and then it will automatically store in another arraylist? Sorry, I don't fully understand

Comment: *"Check if **the word** is a palindrome"* This means that the input is **one word**, not a list of words. The **list is for the letters** of the word.

Comment: create a new arraylist. copy all consonant characters to this new array. do not copy the vowels. so you get a new arraylist without vowels. does that help ?

Comment: I don't have a pattern to follow but I'll try

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create a new arraylist.
> 2. copy all consonant characters to this new array. do not copy the vowels. so you get a new arraylist without vowels.
>
> e.g. arraylist1 = m-a-d-a-m  now irerate over each character of
>   arraylist1 and copy consonants to your new arralylist, arraylist2.
>
> arraylist2 = m-d-m

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PalindromeWierd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //palim contains a palindrome word -> madam
        ArrayList<Character> palim = new ArrayList<Character>();
        palim.add('m');
        palim.add('a');
        palim.add('d');
        palim.add('a');
        palim.add('m');
        System.out.println("Palim with vowels: ");
        for (Character character : palim) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<Character> palimWithoutVowels = new ArrayList<Character>();
        for (Character character : palim) {
            if (character != 'a' && character != 'e' && character != 'i'
                    && character != 'o' && character != 'u') {
                palimWithoutVowels.add(character);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Palim without vowels: ");
        for (Character character : palimWithoutVowels) {
            System.out.print(character);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me some example codes for it? So I can follow.

Comment: sure. I am updating my post.